# Not able to include a header file in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, include

My code looks like this:

```
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>


// define the function's prototype
typedef void (*GL_GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
// find the function and assign it to a function pointer
GL_GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers  = (GL_GENBUFFERS)wglGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");
// function can now be called as normal
unsigned int buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
```

And the command I execute is this one:

```
g++ /home/user/git/tfg_gui/test.cpp -o /home/user/git/tfg_gui/test -I/home/user/git/tfg_gui/include
```

My folders look like this:

```
.
├── include
│   ├── glad
│   │   └── glad.h
│   ├── GLFW
│   │   ├── glfw3.h
│   │   └── glfw3native.h
│   └── KHR
│       └── khrplatform.h
├── test
└── test.cpp
```

The compiler error is:

```
/home/user/git/tfg_gui/test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: GLFW\glfw3.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I think I am doing a really stupid mistake but I have already spent too much time trying to find it. Probably is that I am assuming that something is done in a way that is not the right one.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the compiler error?

Comment: Of course, I forgot to do it. I have already edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the path for the `#include` you use a backward slash `\`:

```
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
```

On a POSIX system like Linux or macOS this is not a valid path-separator, instead it's considered part of the file-name.

You need to use forward slashes `/` on such systems:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Since forward slashes also works on Windows, it's a good habit to always use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using backslashes, convert them to forward slashes.

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Backslashes are escape characters, they are ment to convert regular letters that are always avaliable on your keyboard ( `n`, `a`, etc. ) to special characters that you can't read nor see ( `LF`, `Beep`, etc. ).
In this case, the compiler sees the file name as `GLFW[unkown-character]lfw3.h`, but that file doesn't exist. Thats the source of the error.